# My code is correct, my Droid emulator runs, but the App will not run (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am fairly new to programming. Recently i was following tutorials for Android Development in the New Boston channel on youtube. I understand that there were many updates and changes in the Eclipse software, but i cannot figure this out on my own. I run, the code builds, and the emulator opens smoothly. The app starts to load, but than it closes and says " Unable to run, The New Boston." (Name of the project). I reset the ADB, i uploaded the SDK packages, I've spent all day trying to figure out why the app wont load. Here is the code:
(Mainactivity.Java)
    package com.thenewboston.travis;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter +=1;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter );
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter --;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter );

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

```
Layout.XML
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/your_total_is_0"
            android:textSize="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplay" />
     <Button
         android:layout_width="250dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/add_one"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:id="@+id/bAdd"/>
      <Button
         android:layout_width="250dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/subtract_one"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:id="@+id/bSub"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

thats the code i have, it just will not show up in the emulator window.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should check Logcat output of the emulator. This will show the error message and will help you with pinpointing problems like this. You can view Logcat output in Eclipse.

Checking your code I can't find any obvious error.

I think the problem is in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Please post that. It could be that you forgot to declare the activity itself, or as startup activity in the proper way.